# Why method not return anything after dao method?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

My code stop working after call dao method, if I use GlobalScope code working, but then LiveData not update changes

```
override suspend fun addNewTask(title: String,priority : Int,date: Date): Boolean {
    var isSuccess = false

    val newTask = hashMapOf(
        "title" to title,
        "priority" to priority,
        "task_points" to converterListOfListToJson(listOf()),
        "date" to Timestamp(date)
    )

    val user: User? = userDao.getCurrentUser()
    val newTaskList = user?.tasks?.toMutableList()
    val generatedDoc = db.collection(CollectionNames.tasks).document()
    val userTasks = db.collection(CollectionNames.users).document(user!!.id)

    generatedDoc.set(newTask)
        .addOnSuccessListener { isSuccess = true }
        .addOnFailureListener { Log.e(TAG, "Error writing document") }.await()

    userTasks.update(
        "tasks", FieldValue.arrayUnion(generatedDoc.id)
    ).await()

    newTaskList?.add(generatedDoc.id)
    
    taskDao.insert(Task(generatedDoc.id, title, date, listOf(), priority.toLong())) //after code out

    user.tasks = newTaskList!!.toList()

    userDao.updateUser(user)

    return isSuccess
}
```

This call of this method, addNewTask full complete but after code just end method

```
fun createTask(title : String, priority : String,date: Date) {
    viewModelScope.launch{
        tasksUseCase.addNewTask(title, priority, date)
        tasksUseCase.updateTaskFromLocalDB().collect { //it is not called
            _taskList.postValue(it)
        }

    }
}
```

In DAO I just use annotation update and insert

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(task: Task)
```

My function call in dialog fragment on click, but with viewModel of parent fragment, function deadlock without errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the viewModel was a DialogFragment which was destroyed after the method was called, due to which the ViewModelScope also ceased to exist and the method crashed in the middle

Answer (score 0):

`.addOnSuccessListener { isSuccess = true }` will change the variable to true some time in the future, when the background work is done. Your code that uses `isSuccess` is called before it has a chance to finish the background work.

When you used GlobalScope, it probably used the default dispatcher `Dispatchers.Default`, so you had a race condition and in some cases it could succeed.

When you used `viewModelScope`, it uses `Dispatchers.Main`, so there is no possibility of the result listener being called before the end of this suspend function unless there is some other suspending call in between.

What you need to do to fix it is run your task in a synchronous, suspending way instead of an asynchronous way. Since I don't know what class `generatedDoc` is, I can't help with that. Many libraries include extension suspend function, usually named `await()`, that let you get the result synchronously. If they don't provide that, you can write your own using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. There are many other questions about that on here that you can search for to see how to use it.

Comment: i fixed it but that's not the problem, i added another dao method and now the function stops abruptly after it

Comment: That was a problem, but evidently you have another. You’ll have to share that new code for anyone to be able to help. And explain if there’s a deadlock or if it crashes with a stack trace.